# javascript slideshow is not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, slideshow, fadein, effects

Something is wrong with my Javascript code to make a slideshow with fade-in effects, I'm not able to fix the problem. New slide is not seem to work correctly, I mean photos are not changing automatically.

I was following instructions from a video tutorial of some guy on youtube.com, it was working fine for him, when I followed everything I can from him id did not work for me as it did for him, I've failed to locate my mistake which only I made.

Please help me with the following code:
    
    
    
    
    Slider 1

```
    var nrImg = 3;      //The number of images.
    var IntSeconds = 4;     //Time delay to change the images.

    function Load()
    {
        nrShown = 0;        //The number of images VISIBLE.
        Vect = new Array(nrImg + 10);
        Vect[0] = document.getElementById("Img1");
        Vect[0].style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("S" + 0).style.visibility = "visible";      
        for (var i = 1; i < nrImg; i++)
        {
            Vect[1] = document.getElementById("Img" + (i + 1));
            document.getElementById("S" + i).style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        document.getElementById("S" + 0).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90)";
        document.getElementById("SP" + nrShown).style.visibility = "visible";

        mytime = setInterval(Timer, IntSeconds * 1000);
    }

    function Timer()
    {
        nrShown++;
        if (nrShown == nrImg)
            nrShown = 0;
        Effect();   
    }

    function next()
    {
        nrShown++;
        if (nrShown == nrImg)
                nrShown = 0;
            Effect();

        clearInterval(mytime);
        mytime = setInterval(Timer, IntSeconds * 1000);
    }

    function prev()
    {
        nrShown--;
        if (nrShown == -1)
            nrShown = nrShown - 1;
        Effect();

        clearInterval(mytime);
        mytime = setInterval(Timer, IntSeconds * 1000);
    }

    function Effect()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < nrImg; i++)
        {
            Vect[i].style.opacity = "0";
            Vect[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            /*document.getElementById("S" + i).style.visibility = "hidden";*/
            document.getElementById("S" + i).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70)";
            document.getElementById("SP" + nrShown).style.visibility = "visible";

        }
        Vect[nrShown].style.opacity = "1";
        Vect[nrShown].style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("S" + nrShown).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.90)";
    }
</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="Load()">

    <div id="slider">

        <div id="imgs">

            <img id="Img3" src="images/3.jpg" />
            <img id="Img2" src="images/2.jpg" />
            <img id="Img1" src="images/1.jpg" />
        </div>

        <div id="Snav">

          <div id="SnavUp">
                <div id="Scircles">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="S0"></li>
                        <li id="S1"></li>
                        <li id="S2"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="SnavMiddle">
                <img id="Sleft" src="images/left.png" onClick="prev()" />
                <img id="Sright" src="images/right.png" onClick="next()" />
            </div>

            <div id="SnavBottom">
                <p id="SP0">Roger Federer 01</p>
                <p id="SP1">Roger Federer 02</p>
                <p id="SP2">Roger Federer 03</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have an error: `TypeError: Vect[i] is undefined`

Answer (score 1):

You did not tell whether your code is not running at all or it is running to some extents. By the way, you can always check your javascript code for errors by going to Web Console. Just press F12 to open up the browsers developer tool and look for 'Console'.

Looking at your code, it looks like you're not filling the `Vect` array correctly

change this:

```
Vect[1] = document.getElementById("Img" + (i + 1));
```

into this:

```
Vect[i] = document.getElementById("Img" + (i + 1));
```